# Simeydotme UI slider pips not working on windows

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

hey i am using https://github.com/simeydotme/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips for the custom slider but its not working on windows systems in wordpress.. Can anyone know the reason? Its working good on my ubuntu system . But when try it on my windows system it looks something like this .[image: Windows Image]

When i use my ubuntu it looks like this. [image: Ubuntu Image]

Comment: are browser on both OS the same?

Comment: Yes .. I am using Chrome for both the OS.

Comment: And the version of Chrome is the same?

Comment: No .. I think windows version is advance.

Comment: Doesn't it work with newer versions?

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: I figured it out .. Its due to the cache files .. It wasnt loading the plugin cdn .. When i clear the cache it worked ..